# getting error "make: *** No rule to make target `all'. Stop." while running this command "make all" during installing nagios host

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nagios

Getting error:

> make: *** No rule to make target `all`.  Stop."

while running this command `make all` during installing nagios host

Comment: Could you append your makefile? You might be using wrong indentation

Answer (score 1):

Possible common mistakes:

- Be sure to name the file `makefile` and run the command in same directory.
- Make sure that there is a target named `all` in the file with proper indentation. You can open with `vim` to see if there is an indentation issue.

An example makefile with target `all` could be like this:

```
all: a.c
    gcc a.c
```

If you have trouble figuring out the issue, append your makefile along with the question to help others resolve it.

Comment: this file (Makefile.in) is located under this directory...i am not able to under stand what actually i shoud do?

Comment: You need to rename it from `Makefile.in` to `makefile` Then execute `make all` in the terminal while ensuring that you are in the same directory.

Comment: I mentioned it as the first possible mistake. Please accept and upvote my answer if it solves your problem